# como crear una variable global en Laravel

Tags: laravel

Estoy enviando una peticion con ajax para guardar elementos en mi base de datos. Eso me funcionan bien, pero quiero crear una variable global a la cual pueda pasarle un mensaje y después mostrarlo en una vista no tengo implementado nada aun porque no tengo idea de como hacerlo.

```
Auth::user()->username
```

esta linea de código me permite obtener en cualquier lugar de mi proyecto el username del usuario autenticado. Pues yo quiero crear algo parecido al `Auth::user()` que me permita guardar un mensaje para después utilizarlo en cualquier lugar de mi proyecto. Yo puedo mostrar esto `Auth::user()->username` en mi proyecto sin necesidad de pasarlo en el `controller` para la vista, simplemente solicito esa información poniendo en la vista `{{ Auth::user()->username }}` y listo. Algo parecido a eso quiero hacer. Que pueda tener una variable global y asignarle un dato como por ejemplo: `Auth::user()->mensaje` = 'Hola' y después mostrarlo para que se vea en cualquier lugar de esta manera `{{ Auth::user()->mensaje }}`

Comment: sera una variable de sesion? y si es asi, deberia ir y volver siempre?

Comment: es algo parecido a una variable de sesión. Quiero crear un mensaje y almacenarlo en una variable global y después mostrar este mensaje donde yo quiera. Algo parecido a ´flash´

Comment: ya modifique la pregunta, la verdad no tengo idea de como hacerlo

Comment: ya modifique la pregunta, la verdad no tengo idea de como hacerlo

Comment: Auth::user()->username, esta linea de código me permite obtener en cualquier lugar de mi proyecto el username del usuario autenticado. Pues yo quiero crear algo parecido al Auth::user() que me permita guardar un mensaje para despues utilizarlo en cualquier lugar de mi proyecto

Comment: es que lo que quiero hacer no tiene nada que ver con enviar a una vista desde un controller una variable. yo puedo mostrar esto Auth::user()->username en mi proyecto sin necesidad de pasarlo en el controller para la vista, simplemente solicito esa informacion poniendo en la vista {{ Auth::user()->username }} y listo. Algo parecido a eso quiero hacer esto: Auth::user()->mensaje = 'Hola' y después mostrarlo para que se vea en cualquier lugar de esta manera {{ Auth::user()->mensaje }}

Answer (score 0):

Si aun estas interesado en la respuesta de esto o por si alguien por hay lo neesita, pues lo que buscas lo puedes lograr con variables de session, tan sencillo como añadir un par de codigos:

para crear una variable de session nombre mensaje:

```html
{{ session(['mensaje' => 'Algo a pasado, este es mi dato de mi variable mensaje']) }}
```

para usar dicha variable:

```html
{{ session('mensaje') }}
```

para comprobar si existe una variable de nombre mensaje:

```html
{{ session()->has('mensaje') }}
```

para borrarla:

```html
{{ session()->forget('mensaje') }}
```

Usandolo todo desde blade:

```html
@if (session()->has('mensaje'))
  {{ session()->forget('mensaje') }}
@else
  {{ session(['mensaje' => 'Algo a pasado, este es mi dato de mi variable mensaje'])}}
@endif
  {{ session('mensaje') }}
```